# What does a contravariant and a covariant tensor with the same indices result in?

Tags: metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

For example, for two arbitrary tensors
$M^\alpha N_\alpha$, can this be written in a simpler way like equivalent to a scalar? or does it even vanish entirely?

Comment: If you're not familiar with the notation, $M^\alpha N_\alpha=\sum_\alpha M^\alpha N_\alpha$, because of the [summation convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation). Also note that $M^\alpha$ are the *components* of a tensor, a distinction that is often overlooked in physics terminology but still worth keeping in mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fully-contracted tensor is a scalar. It might or might not vanish.

Comment: Thanks, How would one determine whether it vanishes or not?

Comment: By knowing enough about $M$ and $N$ that you could calculate the contraction. This is similar to asking how you would determine whether two 3-vectors are perpendicular to each other. You can’t say without knowing more about them.

Comment: An example: The 4-velocity satisfies $U^\mu U_\mu=1$ based on its definition, so one knows that $U^\mu \dot{U}_\mu=0$. (Note the overdot on the second $U$.)